# PayPal Access token in live environment

Tags: php, paypal

I have successfully generated a PayPal Access token in the sandbox environment. However, when I change sandbox to live and update the clientId/clientSecret to live codes, I get the following exception:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException' with message 'Got Http response code 401 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token.' in /home/hbooking/includes/PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PPHttpConnection.php:159
```

For some reason it is still trying to access `code 401 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token`

Is there anything else which has to be changed apart from mode and credentials?

```
$sdkConfig = array("mode" => "live");
$clientId = 'removedClientId';
$clientSecret = 'removedClientSecret';
$cred = new OAuthTokenCredential($clientId, $clientSecret, $sdkConfig);
$cred->accessToken = $cred->getAccessToken($sdkConfig);
print $cred;
```

I am using `PayPal-PHP-SDK`. I have unzipped the folders onto my web server directory. However, I do not have composer, is this a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue your php script needs to `require` the `/pathTo/autoload.php` and `/pathTo/bootstrap.php` files. Also the credentials in these files should be updated with your `clientId`, `clientSecret` and change `sandbox` to `live`.

Comment: My problem was that i'm not requiring the bootstrap.php file, required it and it works fine now, you saved me after 3 days! thanks alot.